# How to check if option is already selected in other select

Tags: jquery

Is it possible in jQuery to check if other `<select>` is trying to select an already selected option.

```
<select id="question1">
  <option>questionaire_1</option>
  <option>questionaire_2</option>
  <option>questionaire_3</option>
</select>

<select id="question2">
  <option>questionaire_1</option>
  <option>questionaire_2</option>
  <option>questionaire_3</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects the `questionaire_1` in `#question1` and then he tried to select it again in the `#question2` he should not be able and then `alert` that is already selected.

I have many selects. It must be comparing all. I don't know how to do this TYIA.

**UPDATE1:** maybe they votedown because it was confusing but the thing is the select and it's content was all dynamic and can make a hundreds select.. my apology

Comment: you can either remove and disable the option from second select element based on first select element change event

Comment: Don't you have values with `<option>` ?

Comment: yes it does have and inside the option was also dynamic

Comment: @GelliEspiritu check my answer given below

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#question2").change(function(){
  var selectedID1 = $("#question1 option:selected").val();
  var selectedID2 = $("#question2 option:selected").val();
  if(selectedID1 == selectedID2){
   alert('already selected');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "question1">
        <option value="">-- Choose an Option --</option>
        <option value="questionaire_1">questionaire_1</option>
        <option value="questionaire_2">questionaire_2</option>
        <option value="questionaire_3">questionaire_3</option>
</select>

<select id = "question2">
        <option value="">-- Choose an Option --</option>
        <option value="questionaire_1">questionaire_1</option>
        <option value="questionaire_2">questionaire_2</option>
        <option value="questionaire_3">questionaire_3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using the change event, we will have an array that holds the previous options that were selected, and we test if that array contains the new selected value, if so we raise an alert, otherwise we push it to the array, this code can be optimized to delete the values if we change the option...

```
    var valuesArray = [];
    $('select').on('change',function(e){
      if( $.inArray($(this).value, valuesArray) ){
         alert('u selected the same option before');
      }else{
        // Your logic here
        valuesArray.push($(this).value);
      }
    });
```

Comment: what if i the content reach question100? do i still need to put each id in jquery?

Comment: @GelliEspiritu check now, its generic

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the `val()` when you change the selectbox, like this:

```
$("#question2").on("change", function() {
       if ($("#question2").val() == $("#question1").val())
          alert("Whoops!")
    })
```

Example:
   https://jsfiddle.net/1dfbvpbm/

Answer (score 0):

Check here, it will disable the option from the second select based on first select change

```js
$('#question1').on('change',function(){   
   $('#question2 option').each(function(i,v){
       $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
   });
   $('#question2').find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "question1">
        <option value="questionaire_1">questionaire_1</option>
        <option value="questionaire_2">questionaire_2</option>
        <option value="questionaire_3">questionaire_3</option>
</select>
check this


<select id = "question2">
        <option value="questionaire_1">questionaire_1</option>
        <option value="questionaire_2">questionaire_2</option>
        <option value="questionaire_3">questionaire_3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id = "question1">
        <option>questionaire_1</option>
        <option>questionaire_2</option>
        <option>questionaire_3</option>
</select>

<select id = "question2">
        <option>questionaire_1</option>
        <option>questionaire_2</option>
        <option>questionaire_3</option>
</select>

<select id = "question3">
        <option>questionaire_1</option>
        <option>questionaire_2</option>
        <option>questionaire_3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var previous;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('blur focus', function () {
        previous = this.value;
        console.log(previous);
    }).on('change',function() {
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        var cek = $('select').not(this).filter(function() { return $(this).val()==selected_value }).length;
        if (cek) {
            alert('Nope you cannot.');
            console.log(previous);
            this.value = previous;
        } else {
            previous = this.value;
        }
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/zcoyse68/**

SOLVED!

**OR Alternative way:**

alternative way, you can disable the `<option>` for all other `<select>` once it's selected. e.g:

```
$('select').not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).find('option')
    .prop('disabled',false).filter('[value="'+selected_value+'"]')
    .prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: @GelliEspiritu I've updated my answer & include the fiddle link, please try that :)

Answer (score 0):

note this code check all selects with same **city** class, you can add unlimited select with city class to your document

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .city{
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        width:400px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <select class="city">
            <option value="Tehran" >Tehran</option>
            <option value="Tabriz" selected  >Tabriz</option>
            <option value="Karaj" >Karaj</option>
            <option value="Esfahan" >Esfahan</option>
        </select>
    <br />
    <br />

    <select class="city">
            <option value="Tehran" selected >Tehran</option>
            <option value="Tabriz"   >Tabriz</option>
            <option value="Karaj" >Karaj</option>
            <option value="Esfahan" >Esfahan</option>
        </select>
    <br />
    <br />

        <select class="city">
            <option value="Tehran" >Tehran</option>
            <option value="Tabriz"   >Tabriz</option>
            <option value="Karaj" selected >Karaj</option>
            <option value="Esfahan" >Esfahan</option>
        </select>
    <br />


    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var cityCombo = $("select.city");
            var oldValue = null;

            cityCombo.focus(function(){
                oldValue = $(this).val();
            });

            cityCombo.change(function (event) {
                var currentValue = $(this).val();
                var otherComboSelectedValues = cityCombo.not($(this)).children("option:selected ");
                var canSelect = true;
                otherComboSelectedValues.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == currentValue) {
                        alert("you can't select this item");
                        canSelect = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if(!canSelect){
                    $(this).val(oldValue);
                    oldValue = false;
                }

            });

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```